# Why does gmsh not work in WSL2 after installing from source?

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gmsh

I installed GMSH from source using the following commands in my WSL2

```
$ cd gmsh-4.6.0-source
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake ..
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
```

However when I tried `gmsh --version` I get the following error code `/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory`
Then I tried ``sudo apt install python-is-python3``` then I got a new error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/MYUSERNAME/AppData/Roaming/Python/Python39/Scripts/gmsh", line 4, in <module>
    import gmsh
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gmsh'
```

How to get around this?

Comment: make install is never a way to install python code.. As alternative, whats wrong with `pip install gmsh` ?

Comment: Also, if the cmake is actually able to find a correct location for python code to be installed into -- python definitely has to be available when you make initial cmake call.